# Typing `this` in TypeScript

Tags: typescript

Is there a way to set the type of `this` in TypeScript?

I'm sure there's plenty of uses for it, but in my particular case it's for typing a JS library, and writing a plugin for it.

For example:

```
// Some library
declare var SomeLib: sl.ISomeLibStatic;
declare module sl {
    interface ISomeLib extends ISomeLibApi {
        baseFn(): void;
    }

    interface ISomeLibStatic {
        new (): ISomeLib;
        API: ISomeLibApi;
    }

    interface ISomeLibApi {
    }
}

// Plugin file
declare module sl {
    // Extend the API signature declaration
    interface ISomeLibApi {
        extraFn(): void;
    }
}

module sl {
    // Implement the function
    SomeLib.API.extraFn = function () {
        // Get typing on this here
        this.baseFn();
    };
}
```

Anybody knows a way to do this without a variable like: `var typedThis: ISomeLib = this;`?

Currently the only way I found was having cast it on every usage `<ISomeLib>this` which is cumbersome, and not defined in the type of the function.

Comment: I think this is according to the Typescript spec (chapter 4.2). There is no containing class, so it's a simple function declaration in which `this` is typed to `Any`. Since this seems basic, I assume there is a good reason TS isn't typing it here – but I can't think of it. Maybe someone else will know a reason.

Comment: Relevant feature request you can vote on https://typescript.codeplex.com/workitem/507

Comment: @basarat Thanks, I searched the tracker, but for some reason couldn't find the issue :S.

Answer (score 1):

It can be done as follows:

```
function foo(this: MyType) { 
}
```

You can also use `this: this` to enforce the function to be called on the declaring context, or `this: void` to prevent the usage of this.

However, the target version for this feature is TypeScript 2.0 (although it is already implemented on the latest develop).

See [here](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/pull/6739) for details.

Answer (score 0):

There is no way to hint to the language service what context to apply to the function.

The only mechanism that will cleanly supply type checking and auto-completion without resulting in runtime artefacts is:

```
(<ISomeLib>this).baseFn();
```

Which compiles down to the desired:

```
this.baseFn();
```

Comment: This approach will not enforce the function to be called on the correct context, so you could still supply a different `this` using `call`, `apply` or `bind` and would get a runtime error.